# VMWare Workstation 8 allocating memory

Tags: vmware-workstation

some friends are telling me that Workstation does allocate memory(RAM) from Windows startup even without starting VMWare Workstation is that true?

I have searched the net and I still have no answer.

Answer (score 0):

It allocates virtual memory. Whether or not that memory is backed by physical RAM is up to the operating system.